# Mongoose Update Doesn't Run Before My Res.Send()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

I currently have a controller which is handling the onboarding of a user. When the user completes their onboarding flow, I update their status in Mongo from `New` to `Active`, then send them to a new page. As a method of security, I also have a middleware function on every authenticated route which checks if the user is logged in, as well as their status. If their status is `New`, I send them to the onboarding flow (because theoretically they haven't seen the onboarding flow).

As I run through my experience, when I submit the onboarding flow, I get redirected back to the beginning of the flow. I check Mongo and my status is no longer `New`, so I was confused why this was happening. Eventually I realized when I am sending the user to a new page, the authentication route is checking the user's status before my `findOneAndUpdate()` has had a chance to complete. So the user gets redirected back to the onboarding flow because the last query didn't finish in time.

Any idea how to fix this? I assume it has something to do with async/await but I'm not sure. Here's my code below, I'm working in Node.JS with an express framework. Also, in my post onboarding I am using a mapbox api to get the lat/long of their zip code, which is why I have the `request.get()` in the code.

**Onboarding Controller**

```
exports.postOnboarding = (req, res, next) => {              

var data = req.params.data;    
var final = data.split(',');       

location = final[4].toString();
url = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + location + ".json";
    
request.get(url)
.query({access_token: "private_key"})
.end(function(err, result) {                    

    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"credentials.userId": req.session.user.credentials.userId },
        { practiceSettings: {
            businessType: final[2],
            experienceType: final[0],
            fullFee: final[3]
        },
        credentials: {
            userType: "Active",
            active: true,
            userId: req.session.user.credentials.userId,
            provider: "local"
        },
        paySettings: {
            q1: "undeternmined"
        },
        license: final[1],
        zip: final[4],
        latLong: result.body.features[0].center
        }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {                                                    
                console.log("settings updated");                    
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            }                        
        }
    )

}) };
```

**Dashboard Route**

```
router.get('/dashboard', isAuth, adminController.getDashboard);
```

**isAuth Middleware**

```
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {    

    if (!req.session.isLoggedIn) {
        return res.redirect('/login');
    } else if (req.session.user.credentials.userType == 'Unverified') {
        return res.redirect('/login?verified=false');
    } else if (req.url == '/onboarding') {
        return next();
    }

    User.findOne({"credentials.userId" : req.session.user.credentials.userId})
    .then(result => {                  

        res.locals.user = result;          
        if (req.session.sidebarStatus == 'closed') {
            res.locals.sidebarStatus = 'closed';
        }
                
        if (result.credentials.userType == 'New') {            
            return res.redirect('/onboarding');
        }

        next();
    })        
}
```

And for reference, below is a snippet of my `onboarding.ejs` file which calls the post route. This isn't the whole thing, I have a lot of nested Sweet Alert modals, but this is the important part.

```
Swal.fire({
    text: "Question",
    width: "90%",
    input: "text",    
    inputPlaceholder: "92805",   
    inputValidator: (value) => {
        if (!value) {
        return 'You must fill in this field.'
        }

        if (value.length != 5) {
            return 'Please use a 5 digit zip-code as your answer.'
        }
    },                       
    showCancelButton: false,
    confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
    backdrop: '#FFFFFF',
    allowOutsideClick: false
    })
    .then((result5) => {
        res3 = result3.value.replace(",", "");
        final = [result1.value, result2.value, res3, result4.value, result5.value];                            
        $.ajax({                            
            url: "/post-onboarding/" + final,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
                if ( data.length ) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Error!',
                        text: 'Something bad happened',
                        icon: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText: 'OK'
                    });     
                } else {
                    //redirect user                                
                }
            }                                           
});
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're using `postOnboarding`?

Comment: Sure! I added a snippet to the bottom of my original post, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks, can you also add how you call it in your nodejs code? Something like `router.post(..., postOnboarding)`?

Comment: The post route looks just like the get route for the dashboard, so it would be `router.post('/onboarding', isAuth, adminController.postOnboarding);`